# 14.04 freezes during installation 'copying files'

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, live-usb

I'm installing ubuntu 14.04 on a machine which currently runs windows 8.

I selected the option to completely erase the hard drive and do a clean install of ubuntu. I also selected the options to download updates and install 3rd party software. Ubuntu ran fine off the usb, but now im trying to install it, it copies around 80% of the files, but then seems to freeze. I can still click through the features, and the task bar buttons seems responsive, but the cursor is stuck on the spinning mode and the loading bar hasn't moved for at least 15 mins.

Is it safe to reboot to try again?
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I tried reinstalling without selecting updates, and it sort of worked, but now it crashed (bug report and all) during 'retrieving files'.

Comment: Gonna try downloading 15.04 after my dinner

Comment: I created a new life usb with 15.04

Comment: Now install seemed to go fine, but it froze at 'downloading packages time left 30 seconds'

Comment: Retrying now. So far so good

Comment: Well, it installed, but froze when trying to restart. One hard reboot later, i'm getting black screens and buffer i/o errors everywhere. Yay!

Answer (score 0):

Install it without selecting to install the updates during installation. You can also try again with the latest release Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, try again reboot, re-install if you get stuck again try burning it onto the USB again. (That was my issue first time I got ubuntu) I recommend using Refus.exe to burn it onto your USB.

Refus.exe: https://rufus.akeo.ie/

Comment: Dude he's using virtual machine